# Punny Geography 1

Tags: riddle, wordplay, geography

All answers are real places:

1. I am a town that was placed on the map due to an unfortunate, tragic event. An athlete would see me as the second in a row.
2. I am a major city where a certain superhero wearing his trademark getup would thrive, especially from one of the city’s most iconic sites.
3. I am a major city on a large body of fresh water, in which a certain development on its own island bears the name of a chess goat.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PSE! As a community, we like clarity surprisingly much, so if it doesn't ruin the puzzle: Are we supposed to find three real-world place names? Do they have to be puns, or can we do just trivia or regular riddle solving? Would the [tag:wordplay] tag be appropriate? Thanks in advance, and happy puzzling!

Comment: @Bass It seems likely to me that each of the three clues is in two parts, referring both to a real-world place name and to a punny second meaning of the same word.

Comment: @Randal'Thor thought so myself, but having it stated in the question makes for a nicer kind of puzzle, I think. Now, then, lessee...

Comment: Is there a connection between the three, or are they technically three different puzzles altogether?

Comment: Three different puzzles

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

A town that was placed on the map due to an unfortunate, tragic event. An athlete would see me as the second in a row.

> Lockerbie, Scotland - where a bombed plane crashed in 1988.
>  Locker B - the second locker in an athlete's changing room.

A major city where a certain superhero wearing his trademark getup would thrive, especially from one of the city’s most iconic sites.

> Cape Town - earlier credit @P1storius - is suitable for Batman, and Robben (Robin) Island prison.

A major city on a large body of fresh water, in which a certain development on its own island bears the name of a chess goat.

> Toronto by Lake Ontario - which has Billy (goat) Bishop (chess) airport, aka Toronto Island Airport.

Comment: @JS1 - on same lines Fisher Island, Miami nr the Everglades. The given place is on fresh water. There are a few possibilities for the goat in chess.

Comment: On second thought I think your answer for #3 is actually the correct interpretation of "chess goat" and fits better than NYC/Miami because of the "fresh water" part.  I think you've nailed all 3 at this point.

Answer (score 5):

I have a guess for 2; so posting a partial answer:

> I am a major city where a certain superhero wearing his trademark getup would thrive, especially from one of the city’s most iconic sites.

> The [Hasankeyf **caves**](http://www.turkishculture.org/archaeology/hasankeyf-1082.htm)  are a notable sight for tourists visiting **[Batman, Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman,_Turkey).**

Comment: "trademark getup"?

Comment: If *that* suit doesn't count as trademark getup, what does? For further emphasis: Superman without his getup would still be superman. This guy would just be some rich dude.

Comment: Where is the pun? Try not to think so literally..

Comment: 1. could be [this city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accident,_Maryland). Though I'm not sure how an athlete would see it second. Perhaps rot13(na nguyrgr bayl frrf vg frpbaq orpnhfr gur svefg gvzr gurl zvff vg. Urapr na nppvqrag).

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer to:

> I am a major city where a certain superhero wearing his trademark getup would thrive, especially from one of the city’s most iconic sites.

Could this be:

> Cape Town, South Africa?
>
>  I'm sure **Superman** would love to show off his cape there.
>  However, there are several iconic sites, many of which include the name of the city (Cape Town City Hall, Cape of Good Hope), but none that really stand out in this context.

If this is true, then perhaps:

> The other two cities are the other Capital cities of South Africa - Bloemfontein and Pretoria - sharing a link that way?

On that line:

> The South African athlete Oscar Pistorius (no, not related ;) ), was involved in a tragic event where he shot his girlfriend in **Pretoria**. Maybe another link to that country

Comment: rot13(Rkpryyrag guvaxvat ohg gurer ner znal urebrf jub jrne pncr. Gur BC zragvbaf n fcrpvsvp ureb. Vzcylvat gur trghc-npprffbel vf bayl jber ol gung ureb.)

Answer (score 3):

Number 3

> New York City. Fisher Island, Bobby Fisher being a chess Greatest Of All Time?